# How to include path for Ruby Gems to look in?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm pretty sure I know where my gems are being installed to, but I can't call them. I'm thinking this might be an issue where the gem program is not looking in the right directory for the gems. Can somebody help me figure this out?

EDIT On linux

Comment: We can't see your monitor from here so it's not easy to tell what's going on. Maybe you'd like to tell us more about the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing to do when running into gem issues is enter:

```
gem env
```

This will tell you everything that Ruby knows about your Rubygems environment.

If you are running RVM then enter:

```
rvm info
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux you can set GEM_PATH in your bash_profile or bashrc (or zshrc, if you're using zsh) files. I'm not sure about OSX.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the gem i was trying to install was broken. lesson  is dont rely on tutorials thAT may nbe out of date to help you install gems